# WPF Remove Butto DropShadowEffect on click by ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, controltemplate

In a `Button` `ControlTemplate` I need to access the `IsPressed` event.  How do I do that?

Background: I added a drop `DropShadowEffect` to a `Button` `Style` but got blurry text.  [This fix solved the blurry text issue.](http://www.cplotts.com/2009/02/25/gpu-effects-blurry-text/)  However this added a new issue.  I wanted to remove the `DropShadowEffect` when the user clicks on the button.  Figured I would do it like this;

```
<Style x:Key="DropShadowButtons" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,2,5,0"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Then figured out that `Button.IsPressed` would not fire being part of the `Border`.  So how does the ControlTemplate access the event IsPressed of the Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the trigger on the ControlTemplate instead of the Border's Style. For the Setter to target the Border, you'll need to give the Border a name, and you'll need to give the Setter a TargetName:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentPresenter
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="5,2,5,0"
                />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect 
                        Color="Black" 
                        Direction="320" 
                        ShadowDepth="0" 
                        BlurRadius="0" 
                        Opacity="0" 
                        />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>        
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!